# Getting error while copying folder from one branch to another in gitlab repo

Tags: ios, automation, gitlab, git-checkout

I want to copy folder Test from  gitlab branch feature/Automation-Framework

to feature/Automation-package.  I am using following command

git checkout feature/Automation-Framework-Bhoomi -- AVAPlayFramework/AVAPlayFramework/Test

I am getting following error

fatal: invalid reference: feature/Automation-Framework

How to resolve this error?[image: Below is the image for folder structure which i want to copy]